# Hotel CancelPolicy at HotelPropertyDescriptionRS

Tags: sabre

with these snippet of xml:

```
<RoomRate GuaranteeSurchargeRequired="G" IATACharacteristicIdentification="P02SPD" IATAProductIdentification="P02   CORPORATIVA NET   15" RPH="1">
<AdditionalInfo>
    <CancelPolicy Numeric="00" Option="D"/>
    <Commission NonCommission="Y"/>
    <Text>SUPERIOR DOUBLE /COM CAFE</Text>
</AdditionalInfo>
<Rates>
    <Rate Amount="175.00" CurrencyCode="BRL"/>
</Rates>
```

This CancelPolicy means that the booking can be cancelled until checkin date, or means that booking cannot be cancelled any time?

Tks.

Answer (score 0):

Based on documentation of cancellation codes - in format finder:
https://formatfinder.sabre.com/Content/Hotels/OverviewHotels/OverviewHotelCancellationPolicy.aspx?LanguageOverride=en&ItemID=86780F7703A8439BBEF099536AC02E7E

It seems that means it can be cancelled even the day of check-in (0 days prior to arrival)

You can sign in to format finder using your webservices credentials:
- Agent Sign In = your webservices username
- Password = your webservices password
- PCC = your webservices 'organization'